# Select parent DIV contents based on a containing class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I would like to scrape the contents of a `DIV` based on a class within the `DIV` for example, my page would contain

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p class="foo">some text</p>
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test 2</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result would be:

```
<div>
  <p class="foo">some text</p>
  <p>test1</p>
  <p>test 2</p>
</div>
```

I have tried

```
$.get("https://some.url.com/index.html", function(my_var) {
  console.log($(my_var).closest('div').find('.foo'));  
});
```

But just get an empty result?

Answer (score 2):

You should first find `.foo` and then select parent of it using `.closest()`

```
$.get("https://some.url.com/index.html", function(my_var) {
  console.log($(my_var).find(".foo").closest('div'));  
});
```

```js
$(".foo").closest("div").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    body
    <div>
      <p class="foo">some text</p>
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test 2</p>
    </div>
    body
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Better approach need to target `body` first than find your particular class `find('.foo')` you can view the working example as below :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('body').closest('body').find('.foo').css("color", "red")

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p class="foo">some text</p>
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test 2</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```